# CSS Bug 'on hover' for comment button

Tags: bug, status-completed, status-reproduced, design

If I slowly mouseover the comments button on AD (I have tried with with 2 other SE sites that I cannot replicate this on) I get a rapid flickering between the hover and non hover state when I near the edge of the button, that stops when I go to the center of the button (or move away).

It looks like the button size for the "on hover" css is a couple of pixels smaller than the normal state.  This means that if you touch the very bottom of the button in the normal state, then the on-hover triggers and the button is highlighted, but without moving the cursor is now seems outside the 'on hover' detection edge, and reverts back to the normal view, and repeats on/off until I move the mouse.

This seems to happen on the bottom and right edges, but not the top or left.

[image: GIF]

I made this video to make it clearer http://cl.ly/RHi6

This happens on (Windows) Chrome 29.blah for me, but not on IE8 which renders the button differently (no rounded corners) although it does move everything below the button up a few pixels when highlighted.  Not on a Mac presently to test in OS X.

Comment: I think (but am not sure) that I'm replicating it in (Mac) Safari also.

Comment: Definitively happens in Safari as well http://d.pr/v/EVht

Comment: Happens on Meta too, test by hovering on the add comment button below these comments.

Comment: Right, see linked video in my first comment :-)

Comment: OK, so this bug is repeatable on demand across users browsers and OS - who do we hit with the buggy stick?

Comment: Reproduced here too on FF and Chrome.

Comment: @Shog9 - any progress on fixing it?

Comment: Nope - none yet.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in the recent [site design update](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/site-design-update):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's just a padding problem on the `mouseover` state. This should fix it:

```
a.comments-link:hover {
    padding: 2px 7px 3px 8px;
    ...
}
```